# How to explode a string column based on specific delimiter in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to explode string column based on a specific delimiter (| in my case )
I have a dataset like this:

```
+-----+--------------+
|Col_1|Col_2         |
+-----+--------------+
|  1  |  aa|bb       |
|  2  |  cc          |
|  3  |  dd|ee       |
|  4  |  ff          |
+-----+-----+---------
```

I want an output like this:

```
+-----+--------------+
|Col_1|Col_2         |
+-----+--------------+
|  1  |  aa          |
|  1  |  bb          |
|  2  |  cc          |
|  3  |  dd          |
|  3  |  ee          |
|  4  |  ff          |
+-----+-----+---------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `explode` and `split` functions, and use \\ escape `|`.

```
val df1 = df.select(col("Col_1"), explode(split(col("Col_2"),"\\|")).as("Col_2"))
```